# Loop the Changeble Json and show in to the html

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I have this JSON

```
var b = {
  "Id": 1,
  "ProductCode": 148,
  "Battery": "",
  "OS": "",
  "SimCardCount": null,
  "CPU": "",
  "ScreenSize": null,
  "InternalStorage": null,
  "RAM": null,
  "MemoryCard": null,
  "Have3G": false,
  "Have4G": false,
  "Camera": null,
  "FrontCamera": null
};
```

but this titles is not to be fixed. For example : maybe "Battery" changes to "Color".

I want to show this JSON in to the html  Dynamically

Comment: Do you want to show it in the table??

Comment: Answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: yes 
I show in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop an object for its key and value pairs using Jquery's `.each`:

```
  //loop the object using JQuery each
   $.each(b, function(key, value) {
      //display the key and value pairs however you want
      $("p").append(key + ' is ' + value + "<br>");
  });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/ss1j0s2j/)

Comment: that,s work 
Thank,s a lot  3>

Answer (score 1):

you can loop through the object like

```
for(index in b)
{
    console.log(index, b[index]);
}
```

when the index is an id you can access the elements with

```
var id = '#'+index;
var $elm = $(id);
```

Comment: how to show in the table?

Answer (score 1):

By using $.each you can loop through json obj and bind to your html

//Html table

```
var row = "";
     $.each(b, function(key, value) {
           row+="<tr><td>'"+key+"'</td><td>'"+value+"'</td></tr>"
        });

$("#myTable").html(row);
```

Comment: how to sho in html?!

Comment: Html means doyou want to show it in a table??